# How can I convert a number to text in the excel "datatables.js" download

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, datatables

I'm trying to convert a number as text in `datatables.js` while downloading excel file. If I normally put a single quote `'` manually in the excel file before a number it works.. but when I do that programmatically it doesn't.. where I'm doing wrong? The following are my columns declaration;

```
"columns": [
{ "data": "ID", "visible": false, "searchable": false },
{
    "data": "ProductCode", "title": 'Product Code', "visible": true, responsivePriority: 1, render: function (data, type, row) {

        if (type === 'export') {

            return "'" + data;
        }
        else {

            return data;
        }
    }
},
...
]
```

This is my button declaration;

```
// Initialize Download Button
new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {

    buttons: [{
        extend: 'excel', text: 'Download Excel', className: 'btn-sm btn-success downloadButton', exportOptions: {
            columns: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
            orthogonal: 'export'
        }
    }]
});
```

It shows like this `'12345` in the downloaded excel file but if I just press F2 (Edit) and press enter excel converts it to the text :(. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the single quote?

Just do this `return "" + data;`. It should work.

Comment: This is the way to convert a number to text in javascript. Maybe the issue you mention has to do with excel itself autodetecting the data type.

Comment: I think so or may be the javascript library I'm using I need to debug that.. Its not about excel I guess cause if I do that manually it converts it to the text..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by commenting out below code in addrow function in datatable.js file.

// Detect numbers - don't match numbers with leading zeros or a negative

```
// anywhere but the start
                //if ( typeof row[i] === 'number' || (
                //      row[i].match &&
                //      $.trim(row[i]).match(/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/) &&
                //      ! $.trim(row[i]).match(/^0\d+/) )
                //) {
                //  cell = _createNode( rels, 'c', {
                //      attr: {
                //          t: 'n',
                //          r: cellId
                //      },
                //      children: [
                //          _createNode( rels, 'v', { text: row[i] } )
                //      ]
                //  } );
                //}
                //else {
```

below is the function

```
 var addRow = function ( row ) {
            currentRow = rowPos+1;
            rowNode = _createNode( rels, "row", { attr: {r:currentRow} } );

            for ( var i=0, ien=row.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                // Concat both the Cell Columns as a letter and the Row of the cell.
                var cellId = createCellPos(i) + '' + currentRow;
                var cell;

                if ( row[i] === null || row[i] === undefined ) {
                    row[i] = '';
                }

                // Detect numbers - don't match numbers with leading zeros or a negative
                // anywhere but the start
                //if ( typeof row[i] === 'number' || (
                //      row[i].match &&
                //      $.trim(row[i]).match(/^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$/) &&
                //      ! $.trim(row[i]).match(/^0\d+/) )
                //) {
                //  cell = _createNode( rels, 'c', {
                //      attr: {
                //          t: 'n',
                //          r: cellId
                //      },
                //      children: [
                //          _createNode( rels, 'v', { text: row[i] } )
                //      ]
                //  } );
                //}
                //else {
                    // Replace non standard characters for text output
                    var text = ! row[i].replace ?
                        row[i] :
                        row[i].replace(/[\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F]/g, '');

                    cell = _createNode( rels, 'c', {
                        attr: {
                            t: 'inlineStr',
                            r: cellId
                        },
                        children:{
                            row: _createNode( rels, 'is', {
                                children: {
                                    row: _createNode( rels, 't', {
                                        text: text
                                    } )
                                }
                            } )
                        }
                    } );
                //}

                rowNode.appendChild( cell );
            }
            relsGet.appendChild(rowNode);
            rowPos++;
        };
```